# find maximum allowed ibv_reg_mr

Tags: mpi, infiniband, rdma

I'm trying to diagnose a memory allocation error thrown by ibv_reg_mr() in software that I use, and my suspicion is that it's related to known problems with some Mellanox Infiniband cards where the default maximum memory that can be registered is about 2GB (see FAQ #18 here http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=openfabrics ).

I would like to be able to confirm unequivocally whether this is the case or not so I can quickly negotiate a solution with my system administrators. Being unfamiliar with RDMA and Infiniband, would someone possibly be able to suggest either (a) a simple program that could register arbitrary amounts of memory such that I may trigger the error at the maximum allowed value, or (b) suggest a way that I may determine the way Infiniband is currently configured considering that I do not have root access?

Thanks everyone!

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the parameters for the Mellanox InfiniBand HCA drivers from `sysfs` and you don't need root access to do so. The parameters for module `<modname>` are found in `/sys/module/<modname>/parameters/`. Each parameter is exposed as a text pseudofile there and its value can be read by simply reading the content of the file. You can even do that using standard Unix command line tools.

For the `mlx4_core` module the maximum amount of registrable memory is determined using the following formula:

```
max_reg = (1 << log_num_mtt) * (1 << log_mtts_per_seg) * PAGE_SIZE
```

For the `ib_mthca` module the formula is:

```
max_reg = (num_mtt - fmr_reserved_mtts) * (1 << log_mtts_per_seg) * PAGE_SIZE
```

where:

- `num_mtt` is the maximum number of memory translation table (MTT) segments per HCA;
- `log_num_mtt` is the binary logarithm of `num_mtt`;
- `fmr_reserved_mtts` is the number of MTT segments, reserved for FMR;
- `log_mtts_per_seg` is the binary logarithm of the number of MTT entries per segment.
- `PAGE_SIZE` is the system page size, usually 4 KiB on most current platforms.

Each of these parameters (except `PAGE_SIZE`) can be read from its corresponding module directory in `sysfs`.

It is possible that both modules are loaded. In this case just do what Open MPI does: look for `mlx4_core` first and `ib_mthca` second.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up on this: If log_num_mtt is set to 0 (which it is, in my case), does this suggest that the setting is _actually_ zero? Could it mean that it's rather the default setting? The manual for OFED 1.5.3 says that this value is 20 by default.

Comment: It would mean that there is only one MTT (log2 of 1 is 0). Did you check the settings for both modules? Also module parameters can be configured in `/etc/modprobe.d/` or something.